# Exclude Directory Structure from Image Search

Tags: php, str-replace, trim

I am working on a script to scan an ecommerce site for unused images. The script searches the 'images' folder and its sub-folders for files then creates a list of any images it finds in the following format:

```
image.jpg
product_images/2000/image.jpg
```

The script then scans pre-defined tables in the database to check for references to images, however, the images are stored in the database by filename only (i.e. 'image.jpg') and not by a full file path, so even if an image path is 'product_images/2000/image.jpg', it's stored in the database as 'image.jpg' and the front-end code works out the rest of the file structure depending on the product code of the current product.

This is causing me issues because the database scan is finding 'image.jpg' but the server file scan is finding 'product_images/2000/image.jpg'.

Can anyone please tell me how I can edit the code below to remove the 'sub-directory/' part of what the server file scan is finding?

```
<?php
/*
AZER: (This is an option to set n the code below)
commented out gif and png reports since it give a lot of infos on image type few people use for products photos
*/
require('includes/application_top.php');
set_time_limit (0);
require(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_REMOVE_IMAGES);

// azer modifid to read from configure.php : $root_dir = 'v:/easyphp/www/ms2fr/shop'; 
$root_dir = DIR_FS_CATALOG ;// look in this root

// azer modifid, to read from configure.php :  $base_dir = 'http://localhost/ms2fr/shop'; 
$base_dir = HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_CATALOG ; // for links

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                           ADDITIONAL OPTIONS AND SETTINGS BELOW                                
// if script timesout you may elect to turn off the displays for the list of images
// in the DB and the server, this will free up server resources,
// the lists are for infomational purposes only anyway.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TURN OFF DB DISPLAY
$turn_off_db_display = 0;  // 0 means it is on, 1 means it is off

//TURN OFF SERVER DISPLAY
$turn_off_server_display = 0;  // 0 means it is on, 1 means it is off

// look in this images folder - do not add more folders here - just the main one
$images_dir = DIR_WS_IMAGES; // set to catalog images folder ie 'images'; 

// Check product descriptions for images (set to false to disable)
$descip_check = true;

// Remove images matching pattern from the check, ie put 'thumb' to exclude all images with 'thumb' as part of the name (or directory).
$pattern = '';

// Add links to product images with missing files, only applies to product images (not description) (set to true to enable)
$product_links = true;

// check sub-folders within the 'images' directory (will only go 'one deep') (set to true to enable)
$check_folders = true; 

// exclude the following folders from the check, format must be EX: $exclude_folders = array("banners","default","icons","mail","infobox","pr","links");
// Compare with (if you have it): Select Product Image Directory & Instant Update - Multilanguage V1.15
// catalog/images subfolders to exclude from adding new images
// $exclude_folders = array( "UHtmlEmails","banners","default","icons","mail","buttons","infobox","js"); 

$exclude_folders = array("UHtmlEmails","UNUSED","banners","default","mail","icons","infobox","thumbs","AboutGeyser","Payment_and_Delivery","ProductGuides","Showroom","Contact-us","account_page","Checkout","Returns","Vacancies","brands");

// to add more tables use do it like so: $table_array = array("products_image","products_image_med");
// see below for possible image names
$table_array = array("products_image");

/* Additional possible image names 
,"products_image_med","products_image_lrg","products_image_sm_1","products_image_xl_1","products_image_sm_2","products_image_xl_2","products_image_sm_3","products_image_xl_3","products_image_sm_4","products_image_xl_4","products_image_sm_5", "products_image_xl_5","products_image_sm_6","products_image_xl_6"
*/

// name of this script
$script_name = "remove_unused_images.php";

/* ADVANCED OPTION for SQL query - 
DEFAULT SETTING: get all products even if status is off and there is no quantity
$optional_sql = ""

get image info if the product status is on or if the product has a qty greater than 0 example query: 
$optional_sql = " where p.products_status = '1' or p.products_quantity >= '0'";

get image info if the product status is on only example query: 
$optional_sql = " where p.products_status = '1'";
*/
$optional_sql = "";

// Additional tables to be checked ie TABLE_LINKS
$dbase_tables = array(TABLE_CATEGORIES, TABLE_MANUFACTURERS, 'products_images_gallery', 'products_images_gallery');
// Image Field names within above tables (THESE MUST MATCH) ie  'links_image_url'
$image_array = array('categories_image', 'manufacturers_image', 'large', 'small');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                 //  
//            Do not edit below                    //
//                                                 //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// AZERISH ***** 
//original:  AZER  removed the extra slash : $root_images_dir = $root_dir . '/' . $images_dir;// look in this main images folder
   $sess_id = (tep_not_null(SID));
   if (substr($images_dir, -1) != '/') $images_dir .= '/'; //add trailing slash to images dir if none.. 
   $exclude_folders[] = "UNUSED";

   $root_images_dir = $root_dir .  $images_dir;// look in this main images folder

if (!file_exists($root_images_dir)) die('<center><br><br><b>'.TEXT_LINE_96_1.' ('.$root_images_dir.') '.TEXT_LINE_96_2.'</b></center><br><br>');

// Read the database, then put all existing db images into an array called $full_image_list[]
$sql = "select ";

  $numb_tables = count($table_array);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numb_tables; ++$i)
  {
    $sql .= ' p.' . $table_array[$i] . ($i == ($numb_tables-1) ? ' ' : ', ');
  }
if ($product_links) { $sql .= ', p.products_id '; $id_array = array(); }
$sql .= "from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p ";
$sql .= $optional_sql;

if (require ('includes/configure.php')){}else{echo '<center><br><br>'.TEXT_LINE_110.'</center><br><br>';break;}// login info

$conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) or die("<center><br><br>".TEXT_LINE_112."</center><br><br>" . mysql_error());// connect to db

$select_db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $conn) or die("<center><br><br>".TEXT_LINE_114."</center><br><br>" . mysql_error()); //select the right db

$image_info_query = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die("<center><br><br>".TEXT_LINE_116."</center><br><br>" . mysql_error());

$numb_tables = count($table_array);
// put the images in an array

while ($image_info = mysql_fetch_array($image_info_query))
{

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numb_tables; ++$i)
    {

// ***azerish: *If only jpg format is used*  if (strpos($image_info[$table_array[$i]], 'jpg'))   
if( strpos(strtolower($image_info[$table_array[$i]]), 'jpg') || strpos(strtolower($image_info[$table_array[$i]]), 'gif') || strpos(strtolower($image_info[$table_array[$i]]), 'png'))
{ $full_image_list[] = strip_tags($image_info[$table_array[$i]]);  //put all db images into 1 array
 if ($product_links) $id_array[$image_info[$table_array[$i]]] = $image_info['products_id']; } // store product id for image
    }
}

// Place images from additional tables into the same array
        if (count($dbase_tables) != count($image_array)) die("<center><br><br>".TEXT_LINE_135."</center><br><br>"); 

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dbase_tables); ++$i)
        {

$image_query = tep_db_query("select " . $image_array[$i] . " as image from " . $dbase_tables[$i]);
while ($image = tep_db_fetch_array($image_query)){ 
if (strpos(strtolower($image['image']), 'jpg') || strpos(strtolower($image['image']), 'gif') || strpos(strtolower($image['image']), 'png')) $full_image_list[] = strip_tags(str_replace($images_dir, '', $image['image'])); }

}
// end reading the database for installed images

// get the server images/
  $serverfiles = array();
  GetImageListFromServer($root_images_dir,$serverfiles);

// get all sub-directories of images directory, exlude any in exclude list

if ($check_folders) {

function expandDirectories($base_dir) {
    global $exclude_folders;
      $directories = array();
      foreach(scandir($base_dir) as $file) {
            if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            $dir = $base_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
            if(is_dir($dir) && !in_array($file,$exclude_folders)) {
                $directories []= $dir;
                $directories = array_merge($directories, expandDirectories($dir));
            }
      }
      return $directories;
}

$dir_array = expandDirectories(rtrim($root_images_dir,"/"));


// get images in sub-directories

 foreach ($dir_array as $key => $value)
     //echo $value."<br>";
       GetImageListFromServer($value,$serverfiles);

}

if (tep_not_null($pattern)) {

    sort($serverfiles);// server file list
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($serverfiles); ++$i) // remove any pattern matched images from the server list
    {
        if (strpos(strtolower($serverfiles[$i]),strtolower($pattern))) { unset($serverfiles[$i]); }
    }
    }

  $serverfiles = array_unique($serverfiles);  //remove duplicates
  sort($serverfiles);// server file list

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($serverfiles); ++$i)
    {
     $serverfiles[$i] = trim(str_replace( array($root_images_dir,) , "", $serverfiles[$i]),"/");// remove the root part of the image name
    }

 if ($descip_check)  {
// check if any server images are used within product description & add to db list if so.
    $image_desc_query = mysql_query('select p.products_description as products_description from ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . ' p ', $conn) or die(TEXT_LINE_188 . mysql_error());

    while ($image_desc = mysql_fetch_array($image_desc_query))
   { 
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($serverfiles); ++$i)
                        {
                        if (strpos($image_desc['products_description'], $serverfiles[$i])) $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i];
                        }
    }
    }

// check for images in specific files, ie header.php, index.php etc add to db list if so.
    $check1 = file_get_contents (DIR_FS_CATALOG.DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'header.php');
    $check2 = file_get_contents (DIR_FS_CATALOG.FILENAME_DEFAULT);
    $check3 = file_get_contents (DIR_FS_CATALOG.'stylesheet.css');
    $check4 = file_get_contents (DIR_FS_CATALOG.DIR_WS_FUNCTIONS . 'html_output.php');
    $check5 = file_get_contents (DIR_FS_CATALOG.'skin/css/geyser.css');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($serverfiles); ++$i)
                        {
                        if (strpos($check1, $serverfiles[$i])) { $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i]; continue; }
                        if (strpos($check2, $serverfiles[$i])) { $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i]; continue; }
                        if (strpos($check3, $serverfiles[$i])) { $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i]; continue; }
                        if (strpos($check4, $serverfiles[$i])) { $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i]; continue; }
                        if (strpos($check5, $serverfiles[$i])) $full_image_list[] = $serverfiles[$i];
                        }

  $full_image_list = array_unique($full_image_list); //remove duplicates
  sort($full_image_list);
    $count_db_list = count($full_image_list);//number of images installed in the database
  $count_server_list = count($serverfiles);//number of files on the server

// start the html listing page
```

Comment: Right I've figured out how to do what I want but it breaks the functionality of the code as it then treats all images as being in the same directory.

Is there a way instead to check whether a file path INCLUDES a filename that's stored in the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
$image = 'product_images/2000/image.jpg';
$image_path = explode('/', $image);
echo end($image_path);
```

shows `image.jpg`!

http://3v4l.org/cR5SO

Answer (score 0):

Just use `explode()` function to separate the url by and than choose the last array using `end()` function in PHP. Here is how your code should look

```
$image_url = 'http://yoursitename.com/product_images/2000/image.jpg';
$image_array = explode('/', $image_url);
echo end($image_array); // will output image.jpg the last array
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
basename(product_images/2000/image.jpg);
```